# PHP Won't Send HTML Mail

Tags: php, email, smtp, send

I have an HTML form utilizing the PHP Mail() function. The SMTP server I am using is localhost, and does not require authentication.

```
<form action="../../Scripts/fused.php" method="POST"><p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">

<p>Request Phone Call:</p>
Yes:<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="call"><br />
No:<input type="checkbox" value="No" name="call"><br />

<p>Website</p> <input type="text" name="website">

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Here is the php file:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = 'From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Message: $message';
$recipient = 'hr@example.com';
$subject = 'Fused Enterprises Contact Form';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <hr@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: dev@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers) or die("Error!");

echo "Thank You, the form has been submitted. Someone from the Team will contact you shortly." . " -" . "<a href='/Home/' style='text-decoration:none;    color:#1e90ff;'> Return Home</a>";

?>
```

Do I have to implement PEAR Mail? I have tried to implement that as well and I don't receive the email. I don't know if it is failing or not. The script runs and I get the `echo`, but I never get an email. It did not go to spam folder.

The site is hosted (along with this script) under `example.com`, but the email is using localhost with the smtp server `mail.example.com`. They are hosted on the same server. Might the difference in domain names be a problem?

Comment: When you say "wont send" do you mean that it gives errors or that you don't receive the email?  Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: I am not receiving the emails. I don't have any indication as to whether it is failing or not. I have checked spam folder as well, but it's going to 2 different emails and neither receive it.

Comment: Check your mail logs.

Answer (score 1):

To send mail in HTMl format, Header are most important.
Use this php function..
I am using this script here... http://ieeeaset.com/mailer/mailer.php

```
function htmlmail()
    {
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='WIN')) { 
            $eol="\r\n"; 
        } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='MAC')) { 
            $eol="\r"; 
        } else { 
            $eol="\n"; 
        }
        $recmail = $_POST['toemail']; // address where you want the mail to be send
        $sub = $_POST['subject']; //subject of email that is sent
        $mess = $_POST['message'];
        $pattern[0]="\'";
        $pattern[1]='\"';
        $replace[0]="'";
        $replace[1]='"';
        $mess=  str_replace($pattern, $replace, $mess);
        $headers = "From: [senders_email].$eol . 
        "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol .
        "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
            mail($recmail,$sub,$mess,$headers);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hosts turn off the ability for their servers to send email (so spam from their servers is impossible). I'd check that first and foremost.

Comment: I checked with the host and they said I could use this to send mail, there is no authentication, and that I would have to use 'localhost' as the SMTP server (not mail.example.com), I could not figure out how to successfully implement code to identify that server in the example above.